# Could someone help me prove (P → Q) ↔ (~P ∨ Q) follows from (P ∨ Q) ↔ (~P → Q) in sentential logic?

Tags: logic, symbolic-logic

I need to prove that

(P → Q) ↔ (~P ∨ Q)

follows from

(P ∨ Q) ↔ (~P → Q).

Comment: You could always use a truth table :)

Answer (score 2):

One way to show this is as follows:

[image]

The proof uses the following rules: conditional elimination (→E), disjunction introduction (vI), law of excluded middle (LEM), disjunctive syllogism (DS), contradiction introduction (⊥I), indirect proof (IP), conditional introduction (→I) and biconditional introduction (↔I).  Information about them can be found in *forall x: Calgary Remix*.

---

Maria Vasai requested in the comments that the answer use the premise explicitly. Here is one way to do that:

[image]

---

References

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: Fun thing about this @MariaVasai : Notice that Frank did not use the initial premise!  Of course, since (P → Q) ↔ (~P ˅ Q) is a tautology, there is no need to.

Comment: @FrankHubeny Sorry, what the exercise intended was to make me use the second theorem as a rule in the derivation of the first. Thank you!

Comment: @MariaVasai I added another answer that explicitly used the premise.